# Getting data from MySQL table via Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having issues getting this data from within a codeigniter Controller.

```
    $q = $this->db->get('offers_orders');
    $this->db->select('total');
    $this->db->where('order_number', $orderid);


    $orderdata = $q->result_array();

    $orderamount = $orderdata[0]['total'];
```

Do you see anything wrong with this code ?.

Comment: what issue is it that you are having?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Try :

```
$this->db->select('count(*) as total', false);
$this->db->where('order_number', $orderid);
$q = $this->db->get('offers_orders');
```

OR,

```
$q = $this->db->select('count(*) as total', false)->where('order_number', $orderid)->get('offers_orders');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to defined your select and where method then you call the get() method which are used for get data.

Like this:

```
$this->db->select('total');
$this->db->where('order_number', $orderid);
$q = $this->db->get('offers_orders');
```

And as I see from your query, you need to fetch only one result and for it better solution is to use row() function because this function returns a single result row.

Like this:

```
$orderdata = $q->row();
$orderamount = $orderdata->total;
```

Also to learn more about it you can read [**this acticle**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?> 

</body>
</html>
```